# How to avoid repeated parsing of XML special characters in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am trying to escape XML special characters in a String. The escaping is taken care by a static method as shown below.

```
public static String escapeXml10(String response) {
    return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(response);
}
```

Now the issue with such an implementation is that, I get a piece of string which may or may not be parsed. which leads to irregular outputs.

for eg:

1. & -> &amp (This string is not parsed follows a different flow)
2. & -> &amp; (This string is parsed once by a flow and now by my code).

Now To get a proper response I am planning to introduce a check in the static metod. as follows by using if Condition.

```
public static String escapeXml10(String response) {
    if(response.contains("&amp;")  ||
            response.contains("&lt;")   ||
            response.contains("&gt;")   ||
            response.contains("&apos;") ||
            response.contains("&quot;")){
             return response;
         }else{
             return StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml10(response);    
         }
}
```

is this a correct way of implementing, if not please suggest?

Comment: So, you're passing something that is not XML, to an XML parser? Why do you do that in the first place? The problem is in your flow. You should just not have to do that: it shows a design issue.

Comment: @JBNizet, I am forming an inputs from UI and these values are taken into the xml and then given to a process engine. UI could be like, Browser, command line and few applications. Now this part of the code is an interface which has the responsibility of translating the inputs to a format which is understood by the process engine. I think this is not a design issue. If not please correct me.

Comment: So, if I understand, you're getting input from the browser, and transforming it to XML for the process engine. And you're doing the same with input from the command line, app1, app2, etc. So in the end, every input should be XML, suitable for the process engine. So, why would you have to escape anything, and why would the result be sometimes parsed and sometimes not.

Comment: @JBNizet, These Inputs are entered by the user the user and I dont have any control on those, Are you pointing to this as a design issue?

Comment: So what? A string is a string is a string. Use an XML generator or mapper, give it your strings, and it will generate valid XML, escaping everything that needs to be escaped for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 1st: What you are doing is ***escapping***, not *parsing*.
- 2nd: @JBNizet is right: You have a design issue here. You *must* know what kind of data you should receive in your input parameters: Weteher it is a escapped, valid XML or an unescapped XML.
- 3rd: As a general rule, all user data should be processed by the program *in its plain -unformatted- form*, and with the most specific datatypes: `int` for integer numbers, `float` or `double` for decimals, `String` for texts, etc.
  Then, a proper format should be done *just at serializing* that data. For example, before serializing to XML, nodes and attributes must be properly placed to form a specific data structure, and user data must be escapped to avoid occurrences of special characters within. Conversely, at the time of reading an XML (=parsing), an unescapping must be done (but this is already done by the parser).

Conclussion: You shouldn't even care by escapping if you use standard XML parsers ([DocumentBuilderFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilderFactory.html#newDocumentBuilder()), [SAXParser](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html), [XMLInputFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html)) and serializers ([TransformerFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html), [XMLOutputFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLOutputFactory.html)). Neither should care your client apps.